# Compare and find missing strings in pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas

By having the two following pandas Series, how is it possible to find that df2 is missing 'c'? Or that there is a missing value on index 2.

```
df1 = pd.Series({'col1': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']})
df2 = pd.Series({'col2': ['a', 'b', 'd']})
```

Something that might make it easier: I know that df1 has all the values that df2 has, and I know how many values df2 is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [numpy.setdiff1d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html) on the `.values` of the series, like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.Series({'col1': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']})
df2 = pd.Series({'col2': ['a', 'b', 'd']})

print(np.setdiff1d(df1['col1'], df2['col2']))
```

Output:

```
['c']
```